# What other options do we have for Having?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I deleted my old question to be more precise on what I need.

we have a big query containing lots of smaller queries. This query runs really fine, until it reaches to the "having max" clause:

```
having 
  max
  (
    DateField 
    ) < getdate() - @2_years_ago
```

is there any clause that can be faster than having max? because this is causing an index scan and looping and looping nonstop by the millions of rows that exists in the table.

i tried to do by row_number but got no luck.

And I just notice that this same query runs very well on other databases with the same structure.

just this one ( that funnyly has less rows) it doesnt work.

Dbs on the same server.

Comment: That query has numerous issues: `a` `b` `c` are silly aliases, consider using more meaningful ones. Why is `NOLOCK` splattered everywhere like confetti, what do you hope to achieve with it? The left-join tables are being filtered so you have an implicit inner join, you should just use inner joins instead. Why three subqueries, looks like you should be able to do it in one. `where b.[MerchantLogId] = a.[MerchantLogId] group by b.[MerchantLogId]` makes no sense: you will always have exactly one group so no need for `group by`. You don't need to select anything in an `EXISTS` just `SELECT 1`

Comment: One option is to flip round to `not exists( ... where k.postingdt >= @Today - @lv_2484deletionCycle`. Also, you might be able to use window functions here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your primary issue is that poor cardinality estimation is causing the compiler to reorder the joins. This seems to be happening more when you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, because the server is making different estimations.

You should be able to simplify your current query enough that the compiler will find it easier to

Without seeing your schema it's hard to say exactly, but it seems you can flip around the `EXISTS` logic to `NOT EXISTS`.

- Your original says "ensure the maximum date in the group is less than my date"
- You actually want that there should be no rows in the group which are *less* than the date, so you can say "ensure that there are no rows with a date *more than* my date".
- You now don't need a `HAVING` to find the maximum date.

Your existing query has numerous issues:

- `a` `b` `c` are silly aliases, consider using more meaningful ones.
- Use `[]` to quote column names, not `''`. Don't quote at all unless you have to.
- Why is `NOLOCK` splattered everywhere like confetti, what do you hope to achieve with it? It has very serious implications for data integrity. Consider using `TABLOCK` hints instead, or `SNAPSHOT` isolation.
- The left-join tables are being filtered so you have an implicit inner join, you should just use inner joins instead.
- An `EXISTS` subquery does not need to select anything, in fact it is ignored. You can just do `EXISTS (SELECT 1`.
- Why three subqueries, looks like you should be able to do it in one.
- `where b.[MerchantLogId] = a.[MerchantLogId] group by b.[MerchantLogId]` makes no sense: you will always have exactly one group so no need for `group by`.
- It seems you don't need `NTFM_MerchantLog` in the subqueries, because that is joined by primary key.
- Don't use arithmetic on dates, it doesn't work well. Instead use `DATEADD`

It also seems you can combine the three subqueries into one, by joining all the tables and using `OR` (for this you will still need some left-joins).

Hopefully after making all these improvements you should see better performance

```sql
SELECT
  'NTFM_MerchantLog' AS [Process Master],
  COUNT(DISTINCT ml.MerchantLogId) AS [Registers Count]
FROM
  dbo.NTFM_MerchantLog ml
  JOIN dbo.v_ntfm_merchantlogstatus mls on mls.MerchantLogStatusId = ml.StatusId
WHERE
  ml.CreateDate < @Today - @lv_2484deletionCycle
  AND mls.Status IN ('Closed', 'Expired', 'Reconciled') 

  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.ntfm_merchantlogtransactions mlt
    JOIN dbo.accounttransaction at1 ON at1.accountTransactionId = mlt.accountTransactionId

    LEFT JOIN (
        dbo.ntfm_merchantlogtransactions mlt2
        JOIN dbo.ntfm_merchantlog ml2 ON ml2.MerchantLogId = mlt2.MerchantLogId

        LEFT JOIN (
            dbo.ntfm_merchantlogtransactions mlt3
            JOIN dbo.accounttransaction at2 on at2.accountTransactionId = mlt3.accountTransactionId
        ) ON mlt3.MerchantLogId = ml2.MerchantLogId
    ) ON mlt2.accountTransactionId = at1.accountTransactionId

     WHERE
       mlt.MerchantLogId = ml.MerchantLogId
     AND (
           at1.postingdt  >= DATEADD(day, -@lv_2484deletionCycle, @Today)
        OR ml2.createdate >= DATEADD(day, -@lv_2484deletionCycle, @Today)
        OR at2.postingdt  >= DATEADD(day, -@lv_2484deletionCycle, @Today)
     )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks I'm just more confused on , why the query totally fails ONLY if I let the last "having max" on? If I comment only that part, the code runs in seconds. 

but thanks for the amazing observation I could learn a lot with it.

Comment: Mostly because the compiler completely rearranged the query into a poorer access strategy. Simplifying the query allows the compiler more freedom, and enables it to analyze more of the possible querying options